# Show button only if Javascript loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a button on my site but it should only be instantiated when JavaScript loads.

How do I do this?

`<button>Click me!</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function and initialize it at the end of your script and keep the DOM as @AnoopJoshi suggested

```
<button id = "button1" style="display:none" >Click me!</button>
```

and script would be

```
function init(){ 
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display = 'block';
}

init();
```

Answer (score 2):

Keeep your button hiddden and show it at the time of dom ready.

```
<button style="display:none">Click me!</button>
```

then at

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").show()
});
```

document.ready will fire only after loading all the elements including scripts.

Comment: Downvoter: comment or your downvote is completely useless to everybody

Comment: @mplungjan they do that all the time

Comment: @mplungjan I am not the downvoter but a problem might be with this code is that the button is still in the DOM.

Comment: @BasvanStein thats a good point. anyway lets wait for the downvoter to comment the reason.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi upvoted you, it is exactly the same as the late accepted answer. Why that one is accepted... no clue. Only difference is js vs jquery.

Comment: @BasvanStein thanks man. I was about to comment the same thing. OP doesn't have any manners to comment/read the other answers.  Didn't expect such a behaviour from the user who got more than 1k reputation.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi My apologies. In my pursuit for the quickest fix, I used Vasu's code. I've actually found another solution using the js/no-js class in my head element. I'm going to post my answer shortly :)

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript onload

One way to do that is using either `document.onload` or `window.onload` and add the button to your document.

```
<script language="javascript">
window.document.onload = function(e){ 
    //add or show button
}
window.onload = function(e){ 
    //add or show button
}
</script>
```

If the client does not have javascript it will not execute. The difference between `window.load` and `document.load` is that the first waits for everything to be loaded while the latter only waits for the DOM to be ready.

### jQuery ready

Many people prefer jquery to check for document ready with

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* your code */ });
```

### Add element using Javascript

You can add the button using javascript like this (assuming you want to add it to a div with `id=myDiv`.

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var abutton = document.createElement('button');

abutton.innerHTML = "your text";
mydiv.appendChild(abutton);
```

Comment: No, you can do both. Window.document waits for the DOM to be ready, window waits for everything

Comment: Never used document.onload - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload